# Records are skipped when split-by columns contains NULL values during SQOOP Import

Tags: sql-server-2008, import, sqoop

This issue occurs when the integral column having NULL value is used in split-by attribute.
For e.g.
Col1
1
2
NULL
3
4
In above example, count of rows is 5, but actually only 4 rows are imported.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-2676